# Java DOM Parser XML

Tags: java, xml

I need to extract attribute values from `<Item Name="CanonicalSmiles">` from following XML file (part is shown) ?

I tried `getElementsByTagName("Item").item(12).getTextContent());` But for different `<DocSum>`s item(i) is different (ie not 12 always!)

How do I do this??

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE eSummaryResult PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD eSummaryResult, 29 October 2004//EN" "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/query/DTD/eSummary_041029.dtd">
    <eSummaryResult>
    <DocSum>
        <Id>53359352</Id>
        <Item Name="CID" Type="Integer">53359352</Item>
        <Item Name="SourceNameList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="SourceIDList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="SourceCategoryList" Type="List">
            <Item Name="string" Type="String">Journal Publishers</Item>
        </Item>
        <Item Name="CreateDate" Type="Date">2011/09/19 00:00</Item>
        <Item Name="SynonymList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="MeSHHeadingList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="MeSHTermList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="PharmActionList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="CommentList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="IUPACName" Type="String">2-hydroxy-6-[2-(4-hydroxyphenyl)-2-oxoethyl]benzoic acid</Item>
        <Item Name="CanonicalSmiles" Type="String">C1=CC(=C(C(=C1)O)C(=O)O)CC(=O)C2=CC=C(C=C2)O</Item>
        <Item Name="RotatableBondCount" Type="Integer">4</Item>
        <Item Name="MolecularFormula" Type="String">C15H12O5</Item>
        <Item Name="MolecularWeight" Type="String">272.252780</Item>
        <Item Name="TotalFormalCharge" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="XLogP" Type="String"></Item>
        <Item Name="HydrogenBondDonorCount" Type="Integer">3</Item>
        <Item Name="HydrogenBondAcceptorCount" Type="Integer">5</Item>
        <Item Name="Complexity" Type="String">359.000000</Item>
        <Item Name="HeavyAtomCount" Type="Integer">20</Item>
        <Item Name="AtomChiralCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="AtomChiralDefCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="AtomChiralUndefCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="BondChiralCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="BondChiralDefCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="BondChiralUndefCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="IsotopeAtomCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="CovalentUnitCount" Type="Integer">1</Item>
        <Item Name="TautomerCount" Type="Integer">67</Item>
        <Item Name="SubstanceIDList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="TPSA" Type="String">94.8</Item>
        <Item Name="AssaySourceNameList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="MinAC" Type="String"></Item>
        <Item Name="MaxAC" Type="String"></Item>
        <Item Name="MinTC" Type="String"></Item>
        <Item Name="MaxTC" Type="String"></Item>
        <Item Name="ActiveAidCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="InactiveAidCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="TotalAidCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="InChIKey" Type="String">YIGHIFUVVSYMFG-UHFFFAOYSA-N</Item>
        <Item Name="InChI" Type="String">InChI=1S/C15H12O5/c16-11-6-4-9(5-7-11)13(18)8-10-2-1-3-12(17)14(10)15(19)20/h1-7,16-17H,8H2,(H,19,20)</Item>
    </DocSum>

    <DocSum>
        <Id>53346823</Id>
        <Item Name="CID" Type="Integer">53346823</Item>
        <Item Name="SourceNameList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="SourceIDList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="SourceCategoryList" Type="List">
            <Item Name="string" Type="String">Biological Properties</Item>
        </Item>
        <Item Name="CreateDate" Type="Date">2011/09/01 00:00</Item>
        <Item Name="SynonymList" Type="List">
            <Item Name="string" Type="String">HMS2478O14</Item>
        </Item>
        <Item Name="MeSHHeadingList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="MeSHTermList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="PharmActionList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="CommentList" Type="List">
            <Item Name="string" Type="String">Asinex Ltd.:BAS 02768155</Item>
        </Item>
        <Item Name="IUPACName" Type="String">ethyl 3-amino-3-(1,3-benzodioxol-5-yl)propanoate chloride</Item>
        <Item Name="CanonicalSmiles" Type="String">CCOC(=O)CC(C1=CC2=C(C=C1)OCO2)N.[Cl-]</Item>
        <Item Name="RotatableBondCount" Type="Integer">5</Item>
        <Item Name="MolecularFormula" Type="String">C12H15ClNO4-</Item>
        <Item Name="MolecularWeight" Type="String">272.704800</Item>
        <Item Name="TotalFormalCharge" Type="Integer">-1</Item>
        <Item Name="XLogP" Type="String"></Item>
        <Item Name="HydrogenBondDonorCount" Type="Integer">1</Item>
        <Item Name="HydrogenBondAcceptorCount" Type="Integer">6</Item>
        <Item Name="Complexity" Type="String">271.000000</Item>
        <Item Name="HeavyAtomCount" Type="Integer">18</Item>
        <Item Name="AtomChiralCount" Type="Integer">1</Item>
        <Item Name="AtomChiralDefCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="AtomChiralUndefCount" Type="Integer">1</Item>
        <Item Name="BondChiralCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="BondChiralDefCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="BondChiralUndefCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="IsotopeAtomCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="CovalentUnitCount" Type="Integer">2</Item>
        <Item Name="TautomerCount" Type="Integer">1</Item>
        <Item Name="SubstanceIDList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="TPSA" Type="String">70.8</Item>
        <Item Name="AssaySourceNameList" Type="List"></Item>
        <Item Name="MinAC" Type="String"></Item>
        <Item Name="MaxAC" Type="String"></Item>
        <Item Name="MinTC" Type="String"></Item>
        <Item Name="MaxTC" Type="String"></Item>
        <Item Name="ActiveAidCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="InactiveAidCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="TotalAidCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
        <Item Name="InChIKey" Type="String">NKQHQIJWIYNEIX-UHFFFAOYSA-M</Item>
        <Item Name="InChI" Type="String">InChI=1S/C12H15NO4.ClH/c1-2-15-12(14)6-9(13)8-3-4-10-11(5-8)17-7-16-10;/h3-5,9H,2,6-7,13H2,1H3;1H/p-1</Item>
    </DocSum>
```

Comment: You might want to reduce the sample XML and convert it to a canonical form. You will get better attention that way.

Comment: I would use an xpath compatible dom parser such as dom4j API.

Comment: @Usman: Standard Java does XPath, so why need dom4j?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I like dom4j :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xp = xpf.newXPath();
    XPathExpression xe = xp.compile("//DocSum/Item[@Name='CanonicalSmiles']/text()");
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xe.evaluate(yourdom, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: Thanks it did the trick. Then I printed the CanonicalSmiles with for (int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++) { System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); }

Answer (score 3):

For what you're doing, XPath is likely easier than DOM.  See [this Java XPath tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link to tutorial

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, XPath is the standard way to go. If you're using a tool like [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/), writing XPath is even simpler:

```
String text = $(document).xpath("//DocSum/Item[@Name='CanonicalSmiles']").text();
```

With jOOX, you don't need to use XPath, however. You could also use jOOX's jQuery-like API directly, for instance using filters:

```
String text = $(document).find("Item")
                         .filter(attr("Name", "CanonicalSmiles"))
                         .text();
```

Or by using CSS-style selectors:

```
String text = $(document).find("Item[Name='CanonicalSmiles']").text();
```

Comment: Interestingly enough I am/was working an API almost exactly like yours. - https://github.com/jjnguy/Jinq2XML/

Comment: @jjnguy: Then stop, and contribute to jOOX! :-) jOOX would probably still be missing a LINQ-style API. I'll check out what you already have. Like your class names: `Jode`, `Jocument` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**As I see, the problem of parser each time reading XML elements in different order remained still unanswered.**

XML has not any order of elements. You can't wait that the element read as num. 12 today will be num. 12 tomorrow. The only way to number your elements is go give them numbers explicitely.

```
<Item Name="TotalFormalCharge" Type="Integer">-1</Item>
```

will become:

```
<Item Name="TotalFormalCharge" Num=6 Type="Integer">-1</Item>
```

And you can get it by the attribute value.

Comment: This question has been answered. See the answer above. Anyway, it has been solved and implemented in the software 2 years ago.

Comment: 1.You have more than one problem set there :"But for different <DocSum>s item(i) is different (ie not 12 always!)" remained unanswered. I answered it. 2. The post here are not for the question author only, but for other people as well, for smb. else it could be useful. Here are also some badges that are granted for people, who could usefully reanswer an old question.